# How to Remove Double Quotation from both side of word using Regex python

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove Double Quotation = `"G27707"` I want **`G27707`** this answer

As this is View Source Code of page

```
@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Product","sku":"G27707","brand":"adidas",
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will be no more than one quote on each side of the string, you can use the [`str.strip()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) method like so:

```
result = Productid.strip('"')
```

The `str.strip()` method takes in a string, and removes all occurrences of the string in the beginning and end of the other string. In this case, we use `'"'` because we want to remove the first and last quote.

If no string is specified to strip from the other string, the `str.strip()` will by default strip and leading and trailing white-spaces from the other string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `var[1,-1]` it will remove first and last character.

Answer (score 0):

It works by `result = Productid[1:-1]`

[image]